# Is $K=\{f\mid f\in \Pi_n , \|f\|\le 1\}$ equicontinuous or not?

Tags: functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples

I am trying find that below set is equicontinuous or not:

$$K=\{f\mid f\in \Pi_n , \|f\|\le 1\}$$
$$\Pi_n=\{\text{polynomials of degree }\le n \text{ over } [a,b]\}$$
with norm :
$$||f||=\sup_{x\in \mathcal{D}(f)}|f(x)|$$
I proved that if we change the condition $f\in \Pi_n$ to $f\in \mathcal{C}$ it isn't equicontinuous with use of 
Weierstrass theorem:

$$W_\varepsilon:\mathcal{C} \to \Pi \quad st \quad \|W_\epsilon(f)-f\|<\epsilon$$

So for every $0 < \varepsilon <1$ and $0<\delta$ we have the function $f_\delta(x)=W_\frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{4}{5}\sin(n\pi x)\right)$ where $\frac{1}{n}<\delta$ st equcontinuity doesn't hold:

$$\left|0-\frac{1}{n}\right|<\delta\text{ but }\left|f_\delta(0)-f_\delta\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right|>\varepsilon$$

Which side of conjecture is true?

Comment: What norm are you using?

Comment: Hint: look at the derivative.

Comment: Is the derivative bounded? Should I trying prove it?

Comment: Well, you should be trying to prove it whether or not it's true.

Comment: Equicontinuous where? The whole line? An interval?

Comment: @MartinArgerami: your'e right. Over $[a,b]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without loss of generality you can assume that $[a, b] = [-1, 1]$.
The ["Markov brothers' inequality"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_brothers%27_inequality)
then states that
$$
  \sup_{x\in [-1, 1]}|p'(x)| \le n^2 \sup_{x\in [-1, 1]}|p(x)|
$$
for all polynomials $p$ of degree $\le n$, therefore
$$
 |p'(x)| \le n^2 
$$
for all $p \in K$ and all $x \in [-1, 1]$.
It follows that $K$ is equicontinuous.